# Simple mobile javascript accordion

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working on a relatively simple accordion that works without the bloatware of jQuery and jQuery UI, which I can reuse for all types of occasions. But I just had a roadblock. I can't figure out how to apply it to my current situation, which is - I want to be able to click on the `<section>` element so that it can cover a larger area for the touch, but all I can do for now is not getting me where I want to be.

The markup:

```html
<article id="services">
    Some content
    <div class="flex">
        <section>
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="some image"/>
            <h3 class="accordion-toggle">Title</h3>
            <div class="accordion-content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</article>
```

And here is my accordion snippet:

```
function accordionMobile() {
    if ($(window).width() < 720) {
        var aBtn = $(".accordion-toggle");
        var aCont = $(".accordion-content");

        $(document).ready(function($) {
            aBtn.addClass('accordionButton');
            aCont.addClass('accordionContent');
            aCont.hide();
            $('#services').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function() {

                //Expand or collapse this panel
                $(this).find('div').slideToggle('fast');

                //Hide the other panels
                aCont.not($(this).prev()).slideUp('fast');
            });
        });

    } else {
        aBtn.removeClass('accordionButton');
        aCont.removeClass('accordionCont');
    }
}
accordionMobile();
```

And here is a **[fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/f06qdLh6/)**

Answer (score 1):

Well for a starter for ten. I'd drop all of the '$' since that's all default jQuery calls.

I'd then have a look at replacing all of the jQuery specific calls with Vanilla JavaScript. So no .hide(), .find(), .prev(), .slideUp() etc, etc. As all of those are there for jQuery.

It might be easier to just to look for a plain vanilla JavaScript accordion and work from there instead.

Comment: Yes, @Chris M , while this is true, since I am using jQuery anyway.. I would stick with this version for this particular case, for faster development reasons. My main problem here is choosing what to toggle the appearance of each of the accordion elements.

Comment: In that case why make mention that your wanting to make 'a relatively simple accordion that works _**without**_ the bloatware of jQuery and jQuery UI'?

Comment: A bit of a misunderstandring You are right about everything you mentioned in both of your comments, but my pain is carefully described after that sentence. And I explained in my previous comment that this is just for **quick** test purposes. Thank You for the tips on using vanilla javascript!